# C# fails to parse NaN as a double

Tags: .net, localization, string-parsing

On a Windows PC in Japan, this line of C# throws a format exception:

```
double d = double.Parse("NaN");
```

This line executes fine on my PC in the U.S.

Don't know where to begin troubleshooting this one. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Jim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see what the problem is. Try using the invariant format provider.

```
double d = double.Parse("NaN", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I can help but chuckle like a little kid when I use `double d;`.

Comment: I'll send the user this test. If it succeeds, what does this mean? That they have some sort of Japanese localization turned on in Windows?

Comment: @Jim - That is exactly what it means.

Answer (score -3):

First, you should determine the double value for "NaN". Anyway, parsing non numerical format string will cause System.FormatException, you should catch it and set double value manually.

```
double x;
string foo = "NaN";
try 
{
    x = double.Parse(foo);
}
catch
{
    x = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Actually `TryParse` is the preferred method as it does not rely on an exception for control flow.

Comment: But the variable needs to be initialized to Double.NaN. This value exists in a file that is initializing the double.